# Selecting customer id only if state meets criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to pull some records from a database. For the most part, I need high level details. However, if the state is 3 then I need to extract customer level information.

It looks like this. So far, however, the case statement doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT
    product as product,
    state as state,
    CASE WHEN state = 3 THEN customers ELSE 0 END as customerid,
    SUM(sales)
FROM database
GROUP BY
    product,
    state,
    CASE WHEN state = 3 THEN customers ELSE 0 END
```

I can remove the case statement and just extract the customer number for every state. However, the return is too great. I thought this would be ideal to just get the customer number where it's required, and in cases where it is not required, I would just get a 0. Thereby reducing the size of the output.

Any help of best practice welcome.

Oracle sql

Comment: show all table ddl, sample data and expected output. thanks

Comment: "... the case statement doesn't seem to work" – are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1):

I would just UNION the two aggregates:

```
SELECT product as product,
       state as state,
       customers AS customerid,
       SUM(sales)
  FROM DATABASE
 WHERE state = 3
 GROUP BY product, state, customers
 UNION
SELECT product as product,
       state as state,
       0 AS customerid,
       SUM(sales)
  FROM DATABASE
 WHERE NVL(state,0) <> 3
 GROUP BY product, state;
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` instead, perhaps, and I think `NVL(state,0) <> 3` is the same as `state <> 3`, and you could lose the 0 from the last group by?

Comment: @DavidAldridge I made an edit for the 0 in the group by. I didn't use union all since I though the two entities will not overlap since they cover = 3 and <> 3. I did use the NVL for the insurance in case of empty state since NULL and <> don't mix, because any comparison with null returns false and the condition will not work properly (at least to my understanding).

Comment: The issue with UNION vs UNION ALL is really to avoid an unnecessary uniqueness operation. You're right that they won't overlap, but I'm not sure that the optimizer would know that. Yeah, you're right about the state and the NVL – my bad